# Bind Parent to a Observable List

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I want to bind the `VBox.getChildren()` `ObservableList` to my own `ObservableList`. So that, when ever my process detects an Image, it is added to my list which in turn automatically is added to the VBox.

```
 Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(myList,vbox.getChildren());
```

It throws the below exception:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Is there any other way of doing it? What is the issue above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a problem with binding, your approach is correct. You may be getting `UnsupportedOperationException` due to older versions of FX.

E.g. next example works for me using JavaFX 2.2:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ObservableList<Node> list = FXCollections.<Node>observableArrayList();
    VBox root = new VBox();

    Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(list, root.getChildren());
    list.add(new Button("Test"));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```